# How to Call Variable from Java to HTML?

Tags: javascript, java, html

I would like to call some variable (`code` and `name` -- String) from java class on html class (`<label>`). And I wonder whether it can be directly applied (without using jsp)? Or it necessary to use javascript?

And if it requires javascript I have added the code below, but it's not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     document.getElementById("lists").innerHTML = name;
</script>
```

And also this is my java file that store variable `code` and `name`.

```
List<Names> nameList = Common.getNameList(data.getName());
for (int i = 0; i < nameList.size(); i++) {
     System.out.println(nameList.get(i).code + "=" + whsList.get(i).name);
}
```

And in HTML I had,

```
<div id="lists">
     <label>Code<label>
     <label>Name<label>
</div>
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: there is no direct relation with `Java` and `HTML`. In a Webserver- client environment both can communicate with HTML via HTTP

Comment: you will need javascript for this ... use ajax if no page load is required

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't directly. JavaScript is executed on the client side (browser)
JavaScript is client side scripting lang. and 'Java' run on server side. so you need to send  request to server . if you want to use java lang on server side then we need to use servlet or framework like a spring, struts etc.
if you want to use java variable in client side JavaScript then send request to server. you can send request using ajax and send nameList in JSON type from servlet as response then all list available to use in JavaScript  ... so you need to refer some example like ...

new link i hope this help
http://www.technicalkeeda.com/jquery/spring-framework-jquery-ajax-request-and-json-response-example

Comment: Actually I use spring framework for server side. Ok, maybe I'll try your reference first. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.technicalkeeda.com/jquery/spring-framework-jquery-ajax-request-and-json-response-example

Comment: I'm using spring version 4.0.0.RELEASE.

Comment: good, and client site which extensions page used  mean .HTML OR JSP

Comment: i add new link i hope this helpl